# How can Custom Post Type and a page have the same slug?

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

I have a page called "Art" that can be viewed at `/art`.  I also have a custom post type called "samples" with a post called "Art" inside of it. It SHOULD be viewed at `/samples/art`.  For some reason, instead of having `/samples/art` as the URL, WordPress is forcing `/samples/art-2`.

The Art page and the Art post are two completely irrelevant pieces of data. Is there any way to let both of these entities exist with a clean URL?

Comment: Somewhere in your custom post type, there can be a draft or deleted post that had the slug `art`. I think that forced the Sample's post to get `/samples/art-2`. If that previous post can be deleted permanently, your desired slug for Sample's post can be acquired.

Comment: Yah I thought that might be the case too, but there doesn't seem to be anything else.  As a second test, I went to the page and changed it's slug to /artx and then I was able to make the art post type /samples/art.  So it's definitely the page that is blocking the post type's slug.

Comment: Since a page and a CPT would generate the same permalink (under the right conditions) it doesn't surprise me that you are having trouble with this.

Comment: Is your samples CPT hierarchical (and if it needs to be)? Try switching it not hierarchical.

Comment: Yes it is hierarchical; under Art I list some specific examples.  This sounds like an extremely limiting design flaw in Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug (or design flaw) that seems be getting some attention by the Wordpress team.  Take a look at this discussion https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18962 for more information.  As of Wordpress 4.0 this is still an issue.

Comment: Thank you for finally clearing this up!  Good to know they're actively working on a solution.